# Solidity Proxies, Multiple Inheritance, and Storage Slots

Tags: proxy, storage, solidity, multiple-inheritance

Foundation for questions: scenario where multiple parent (base) contracts are inherited:

```
contract Base1 {
    // do something
    uint256[1000] private __gap;
}

contract Base2 {
    // do something
    uint256[1000] private __gap;
}

contract Child is Base1, Base2 {
    uint256 testVariable = 123;
}
```

Questions:

1. If a large storage gap is left, you could theoretically replace `Base2` with two new contracts (ex: `Base2A` and `Base2B`), so long as the storage used, including gaps, for both sums to the total gap left by the original Base2, right?
2. On implementation upgrades, **[since storage variables from previous implementations can't be removed](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable#modifying-your-contracts)**, but byte code can nevertheless be reduced (ex: nuking `Base2`'s code), each proxy upgrade is still ultimately constrained by the max contract size. To be clear, the available bytecode space would be `24576 bytes - contract_to_replace_size`. Given that the legacy storage variables from `Base2` are still taking up storage slots, they would eat into the available bytecode space for implementation upgrades, correct? In other words, even if, like in #1, large gaps were left, you cant continue replacing parent contracts forever, because each replacement leaves behind non-removable storage variables that eats into contract size?

Trying to better understand the constraints on optionality.